# How to increase performance of EJB application

Tags: ejb-3.0

I am working on an EJB 3.2 based application from the last 7 months.
It uses jboss final 7.0 server and oracle database.
for front end jsf is used.

Now it seems that due to increase in data, the system is running slow now.

Is their any way to increase the performance of the system, like changing server, or anything else we can do.

Comment: Some system being EJB system or not , to improve performance , first we need to find bottlenecks & we find bottlenecks by extensive logging and bench marking. Also, I guess nobody would be able to suggest without looking at your code.

Comment: its an standalone application running on client server.. So how I can find bottlenecks....

Comment: You need to write to test code to simulate business logic calls i.e. simulate user behavior via your own calling code.

Comment: any other option like migration of server, increase in ram, etc

Comment: Adding infra to improve performance is something that any tom dick & harry can do, that requires no analysis. Hows adding infra going to help if there happens to be a bottleneck in code ? Optimized usage of resources is what a programmer supposed to do.